# Compare Two Files Using awk Script

Tags: awk

I need to validate two files using condition and each record in file is separated using comma.

File1

```
Prakash,10,20,3(Field Index)
```

File2

```
10,25,100
20,25,200
30,20,300
```

From reading the file 1 FieldIndex I need to sum the corresponding column in File 2(ie 100+200+300) needs to be added.

Comment: What did you try? How do you know if it is the 3rd field or just the last one or...? Also, note that it is good to give feedback to the answerers to your questions. You've asked a few so far and haven't accepted any, neither dear to format properly. Try to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please clarify your question.  You talk about 100+200+300, but it is not remotely clear how you get to those numbers given the entry in the first file.  Does the file contain the words `(Field Index)`, or is that commentary?  Are you looking to add the numbers in the column of the second file identified by the column number in the last column of the first file?  So if the last column said 2, you'd be adding 25+25+20?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat > file1
Prakash,10,20,3
$ awk -F, '
  NR == FNR {f = $NF; next}  # last field of the first file
  { sum += $f }              # we're in the 2nd file here since NR != FNR
  END { print "sum of field index " f " is " sum }
' file1 file2 
sum of field index 3 is 600
```

Comment: Code-only answers are auto-flagged as low quality and as such are discouraged on stackoverflow. In the future please embellish your answer with details and explain why it is a solution to the question. This helps other users.